# Mangling the words of a sentence

Tags: c++

[**Original Problem Statement**](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/3aqvjn/20150622_challenge_220_easy_mangling_sentences/)

---

> **Problem Analysis**
>
> Task: Given a sentence, mangle each word and output the result.
>
> Clarifications:
>
> *Mangling* will be defined as a word with its characters in case-insensitive order.  The case of the original character is
>   preserved at the same location in the resulting mangled word (e.g.,
>   `Oh` becomes `Ho`).  Punctuation location should be preserved.
>
> A *sentence* is a collection of words separated by spaces (and only
>   spaces). A *word* is a grouping of non-space symbols.  *Punctuation* is any non-alphanumeric or space character.

---

**Tests**

Input 1:

> This challenge doesn't seem so hard.

Output 1:

> Hist aceeghlln denos't eems os adhr.

Input 2:

> There are more things between heaven and earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy.

Output 2:

> Eehrt aer emor ghinst beeentw aeehnv adn aehrt, Ahioort, ahnt aer ademrt fo in oruy hhilooppsy.

---

**Solution** *[Wandbox Live Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/w5eKkImbaeeCUyae)*

My approach was to sort the values using merge sort and in-place merge.  Unfortunately, the STL doesn't provide a merge sort over two or more separated ranges (only adjacent ranges).  The original input is not tokenized.  Instead, I generate the range of all tokens and operate on those ranges.

Primary solution with simple driver:

```
#include "MyAlgorithms.h"

#include <cctype>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename Iterator, typename Comparator>
void inplace_mangle(Iterator first, Iterator last, Comparator comp) {
  const auto isupper_locations = my::collect_if(first, last, ::isupper);

  for (auto &loc : isupper_locations) {
    *loc = ::tolower(*loc);
  }

  const auto word_ranges = my::collect_ranges_if(first, last, ::isalnum);

  my::sort_ranges(word_ranges, comp);
  my::inplace_merge_ranges(word_ranges, comp);

  for (auto &loc : isupper_locations) {
    *loc = ::toupper(*loc);
  }
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> sentences = {
    "This challenge doesn't seem so hard.",
    "There are more things between heaven and earth, Horatio, than are "
    "dreamt of in your philosophy.",
    "Eye of Newt, and Toe of Frog, Wool of Bat, and Tongue of Dog.",
    "Adder's fork, and Blind-worm's sting, Lizard's leg, and Howlet's wing.",
    "For a charm of powerful trouble, like a hell-broth boil and bubble." };

  const std::vector<std::string> solutions = {
    "Hist aceeghlln denos't eems os adhr.",
    "Eehrt aer emor ghinst beeentw aeehnv adn aehrt, Ahioort, ahnt aer "
    "ademrt fo in oruy hhilooppsy.",
    "Eey fo Entw, adn Eot fo Fgor, Loow fo Abt, adn Egnotu fo Dgo.",
    "Adder's fkor, adn Bdilm-nors'w ginst, Adilrs'z egl, adn Ehlost'w ginw.",
    "For a achmr fo eflopruw belortu, eikl a behh-llort bilo adn bbbelu." };

  for (auto &sentence : sentences) {
    const auto words =
      my::collect_ranges_if_not(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), ::isspace);

    for (auto &word : words) {
      inplace_mangle(word.begin(), word.end(), std::less<char>());
    }
  }

  auto current_solution = solutions.begin();
  for (const auto &sentence : sentences) {
    std::cout << sentence << '\n';
    std::cout << "Passed? " << std::boolalpha << (sentence == *current_solution++)
              << "\n\n";
  }
}
```

`<MyAlgorithms.h>` Library (Applicable Functions)

```
#ifndef MY_ALGORITHMS_H_INCLUDED
#define MY_ALGORITHMS_H_INCLUDED

#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

namespace my {
  template <typename Iterator> class BasicRangeIterator {
    Iterator first;
    Iterator last;

  public:
    explicit BasicRangeIterator(Iterator first, Iterator last)
      : first(first), last(last) {}
    Iterator begin() const { return first; };
    Iterator end() const { return last; };

    bool operator==(const BasicRangeIterator &rhs) const {
      return first == rhs.first && last == rhs.last;
    }

    bool operator!=(const BasicRangeIterator &rhs) const { 
      return *this != rhs; 
    }
  };

  template <typename InputIterator, typename UnaryPredicate,
            typename ResultType = std::vector<BasicRangeIterator<InputIterator>>>
  ResultType collect_ranges_if(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                               UnaryPredicate pred) {
    ResultType result;

    for (auto mid = first; true; ++mid) {
      first = std::find_if(mid, last, pred);
      mid = std::find_if_not(first, last, pred);
      result.emplace_back(first, mid);

      if (mid == last) {
        break;
      }
    }

    return result;
  }

  template <typename InputIterator, typename UnaryPredicate,
            typename ResultType = std::vector<BasicRangeIterator<InputIterator>>>
  ResultType collect_ranges_if_not(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                                   UnaryPredicate pred) {
    ResultType result;

    for (auto mid = first; true; ++mid) {
      first = std::find_if_not(mid, last, pred);
      mid = std::find_if(first, last, pred);
      result.emplace_back(first, mid);

      if (mid == last) {
        break;
      }
    }

    return result;
  }

  template <typename InputIterator, typename UnaryPredicate,
            typename ResultType = std::vector<InputIterator>>
  ResultType collect_if(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                        UnaryPredicate pred) {
    ResultType result;

    first = std::find_if(first, last, pred);

    while (first != last) {
      result.push_back(first);
      first = std::find_if(++first, last, pred);
    }

    return result;
  }

  template <typename BidirIterator, typename Comparator>
  void inplace_merge(BidirIterator lower_first, BidirIterator lower_last,
                     BidirIterator upper_first, BidirIterator upper_last,
                     Comparator comp) {
    for (; upper_first != upper_last; ++upper_first) {
      auto pivot = std::upper_bound(lower_first, lower_last, *upper_first, comp);

      if (pivot != lower_last) {
        std::rotate(pivot, std::prev(lower_last), lower_last);
        std::iter_swap(pivot, upper_first);
      }
    }
  }

  template <typename IteratorPairedRange, typename Comparator>
  void sort_ranges(const IteratorPairedRange &ranges, Comparator comp) {
    for (auto &range : ranges) {
      std::sort(std::begin(range), std::end(range), comp);
    }
  }

  template <typename BidirIteratorPairRange, typename Comparator>
  void inplace_merge_ranges(const BidirIteratorPairRange &range,
                            Comparator comp) {
    for (auto &upper : range) {
      for (auto &lower : range) {
        if (lower == upper) {
          break;
        }

        inplace_merge(std::begin(lower), std::end(lower), std::begin(upper),
          std::end(upper), comp);
      }
    }
  }
} // namespace my
#endif // MY_ALGORITHMS_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Rather than using make-shift tests in `main()`, you may wish to look into actual unit tests.

Comment: I kinda just wrote it on wandbox over a slow period right before and during my lunch break. The driver was just included to show that it does compile and does work.  I had smaller tests for the individual components, but didn't include them.

Comment: OK, just thought you might be interested.

Comment: For some reason, I didn't even think to use the Boost test library when writing it.  Definitely should have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (auto mid = first; true; ++mid) {
  ...
  if (mid == last) {
    break;
  }
}
```

looks strange. Why not

```
for (auto mid = first; mid != last; ++mid)
```

If you want to ensure that the body is executed at least once, use `do ... while()`.

I am not sure I understand what do you mean by *merge sort over two or more separated ranges*. At least I don't see where the sorting separate ranges is called for. Mangling in-place each word (or `range`) independently seem to suffice.

Comment: I suppose I should have just made the `for` a `while`.  The reason I pulled the conditional is you can't increment the iterator beyond `end()`.  If I search a range and the last entry is `mid == end()`, the `for` will attempt to increment and be out of range.

Comment: A `for` condition `mid != end()` is executed before `mid` is incremented, so you are safe. The only difference is that in your code a loop body is executed even if `first == end()1 at the very beginning. Is it intended?

Comment: Since I had the loop searching for both the start and end of the subranges at the same time, `mid` ends up updating in the loop and becoming `last` is a concern that had to be addressed as I didn't want to increment beyond `last`.  I probably should have avoided trying to handle all the range cases (empty, single, many) and instead split out the special empty range by itself.  Definitely a poor decision for readability.

Comment: As for your second concern, the problem requires that the alphanumerics in a word be sorted.